# Can decorators modify type hints in the function signature of wrapped functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of functions that look like this:

```
def insert_user(user: User, db: Connection) -> None:
    ...

def add_role_to_user(user: User, role: str, db: Connection) -> None:
    ...

def create_post(post: Post, owner: User, db: Connection) -> None:
    ...

# etc.
```

What these functions all have in common is that they take a `Connection` parameter called `db` that they use to modify a database. For performance reasons, I want the functions to be able to pass the `db` parameter between each other and not create a new connection every time. However, for convenience reasons, I also don't want to have to create and pass the `db` parameter every time I call the functions myself.

For that reason I have created a decorator:

```
def provide_db(fn):
    ...
```

This decorator checks if the keyword arguments contain the key "db", and if not, it creates a connection and passes it to the function. Usage:

```
@provide_db
def insert_user(user: User, db: Connection) -> None:
    ...
```

This works perfectly! I can now call the database functions without worrying about connecting to the database, and the functions can pass the db parameters to each other.

However, for this to be typed properly, the decorator needs to modify the function signature of the wrapped function, changing the `db` parameter from `Connection` to `Optional[Connection]`.

Is this currently possible with Python's type hints? If so, how is it done?

---

This is the `provide_db` function:

```py
def provide_db(fn):
    """Decorator that defaults the db argument to a new connection

    This pattern allows callers to not have to worry about passing a db
    parameter, but also allows functions to pass db connections to each other to
    avoid the overhead of creating unnecessary connections.
    """

    if not "db" in fn.__code__.co_varnames:
        raise ValueError("Wrapped function doesn't accept a db argument")

    db_arg_index = fn.__code__.co_varnames.index("db")

    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Result:
        if len(args) > db_arg_index and args[db_arg_index] is not None:
            pass  # db was passed as a positional argument
        elif "db" in kwargs and kwargs["db"] is not None:
            pass  # db was passed as a keyword argument
        else:
            kwargs["db"] = connect()

        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.__annotations__ = Optional[fn.__annotations__["db"]]

    return wrapper
```

Comment: In hindsight, this would probably have been better solved by connection pooling, keeping the connection logic out of the business logic altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since python 3.10 you can now type this correctly using `ParamSpec` generic with `Concatenate` to remove arguments from a signature.

The following code type checks correctly in python 3.11 with mypy and pylance.

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, Concatenate
from functools import wraps

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

class DB:
    pass

db = DB()

def provide_db(fn: Callable[Concatenate[DB, P], R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return fn(db, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@provide_db
def foo(db: DB, x: int) -> int:
    return x

foo(1)
```

For more information about using `ParamSpec` to modify call signatures statically see [PEP 612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/)

Please note that I removed the dynamic checking/adding of the DB argument resulting in an optional DB argment as this complicates matters further, especially since the ParamSpec does not support keyword arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Function annotations are documented as writable in [the datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/).

Follow this simplified example:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional

def provide_db(func):
    func.__annotations__["db"] = Optional[func.__annotations__["db"]]
    return func

@provide_db
def f(db: Connection):
    pass

print(f.__annotations__)
```

Comment: Very interesting. I'm curious if Mypy will notice the changes to the annotations, I will give it a shot.

Comment: The `__annotations__` attribute doesn't appear to affect either Mypy or my language server (pylance). They both assume the function signature of all wrapped functions are the signature of the function returned from `provide_db`, i.e. `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)`. This means I get no intellisense in my editor, and mypy accepts absolutely any input for the decorated functions.

Comment: That sounds to me as though you aren't calling [`update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper). Are you using `functools.wraps` or similar anywhere? Try putting it above your `def wrapper(...)` within the decorator's body. My simplified example doesn't need it, because I didn't use a wrapper function.

Comment: True, I had never heard of `update_wrapper` before you just mentioned it. I have added it now, though. I have added the source code of `provide_db` to my question so you can verify. Mypy still accepts any input to the function. The language server now sees the type of all my decorated functions as `_AnyCallable`, so it still doesn't give me any intellisense features.

Comment: Also I just found this Python issue, which makes it sound like what I'm trying to do it currently impossible: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3157

Answer (score 2):

For this requirement, it seems be good to have all these functions in a class.

```
class DbOps(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.__db = db

    def insert_user(user: User) -> None:
        #use self__.db to connect db and insert user
```

Then :

```
db_ops = DbOps(db)
db_ops.insert_user(...)
etc
```

Comment: True, seems I will have to refactor my codebase like this if I want to have type hints